# How to get SpecUnit to run within a TeamCity CI build

Tags: c#, nant, teamcity

I am trying to get SpecUnit to run in a continuous integration build using Nant. At the moment the files are in the correct place but no output is generated from SpecUnit.Report.exe. Here is the relevant task from the nant build script:

```
<echo message="**** Starting SpecUnit report generation ****" />
<copy file="${specunit.exe}" tofile="${output.dir}SpecUnit.Report.exe" />
<exec program="${output.dir}SpecUnit.Report.exe" failonerror="false">
    <arg value="${acceptance.tests.assembly}" />
</exec>
```

Please note:

- `${specunit.exe}` is the full path to where “SpecUnit.Report.exe” is located.
- `${output.dir}` is the teamcity output directory for the current build agent.
- `${acceptance.tests.assembly}` is "AcceptanceTests.dll"

Anyone tried this before?

Comment: remember you can use the report in the build summary as another tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the full path to the assembly argument I think...

```
   <exec program="${output.dir}SpecUnit.Report.exe" verbose="true">
      <arg value="${output.dir}${acceptance.tests.assembly}" />
    </exec>
```